# How many "AND" can you have on a SpringData query?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've created this method:

```
    Long getAttributesAfterTimeSent(String x, String y, Long timeSent) { 
        return repository.countByXAndYAndZTypesAndTimeSentGreaterThanEqual(
                   x, 
                   y, 
                   new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("attribute1"); add("attribute2"); }}, 
                   timeSent);
    }
```

The signature of this method in the repository is as follows:

```
Long countByXAndYAndZTypesAndTimeSentGreaterThanEqual(String x, String y, Collection<String> attributeTypes, timeSent);
```

When I run it, i get the following error:

```
13:18:40.784 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
13:18:41.014 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1797, SQLState: 42000
13:18:41.014 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL error: 1797 ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please put the contents of the method as a code block, this would be very useful and helpful.

Comment: `time` should be `timeSent` please provide us with a minimal example with real code

Comment: please see edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer.

One of my types was a non-scalar type the: **ArrayList.**

For cases like this we need to use the *IN* keyword in the JPA method.

So when changing the method from

`countByXAndYAndZTypesAndTimeSentGreaterThanEqual`

to

`countByXAndYAndZTypesInAndTimeSentGreaterThanEqual`

it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly has nothing to do with the number of `AND` phrases in your method. 
The limit is only implicit through something like maximum method name length, maximum query length, maximum number of parameters.
It will be way higher than anything any sane person will try to cram in a single method name.

[The cause of the exception](https://benjamindba.blogspot.com/2012/10/ora-01797-this-operator-must-be.html) you are seeing is:

> CAUSE:
>   equal operator = followed by multiple value like (1,2)

This probably means: one of the parameters or maybe some of the attributes is not of scalar type, but some kind of collection or array.

If these leads you toward something you can't easily express through a method name use a `@Query` annotation and provide the exact query you need to execute.

Comment: i have another one of my methods which has a collection, but that is no issue there.

Comment: Then show use the code of your entities, the declaration of the method in question and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: "one of the parameters ... is not of of scalar type" and there you are the third parameter is a collection. You can't compare anything with a collection for equality with JPA/SQL. The solution to this depends on the type of  `ZTypes` which you still haven't shown and what logical operation you actually want to perform.

Comment: The Ztypes are just an ArrayList<String> .... In regard to using a non-scalar type, I have used the same ArrayList<String> in a method with JPA signature like this: findTopByXsDAndZTypeInOrderByTimeDesc ....where Xs is a String, and Ztype is an ArrayList<String>. But this one wokrs fine.

Comment: I was missing the `IN` keyword for the non-scalar type. Thanks for your help.